# How to use Java's Observable and Observer with JPA Entities correctly?

Tags: java, jpa, observer-pattern

I have two entities:

```
    @Entity
    public class A extends Observable {

        @Id
        private int id;

    }

    @Entity
    public class B implements Observer {

        @Id
        private int id;

        @ManyToMany
        private List<A> observableList;

        public void addObservable(A observable){
           observableList.add(observable);
           observable.addObserver(this); //How will this get persisted 
                                        // as it gets added in the super 
                                        //class Observable which is not an entity?
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg){
              //update methods
        }
    }
```

My objective is to notify B, whenever any of its observables change. Therefore I was looking at the Observer/Observable of JDK.

The problem which I am facing is how any of the added Observers get persisted?

A possible way which I could think: Maintain list of Observers also in the subclass A and do a post load operation to add observers to Observable superclass:

```
     @Entity
     public class A extends Observable {

            @Id
            private int id;

            @OneToMany  
            private List<B> observers;

            @PostLoad
            public void initialize(){
               for(B b : observers){
                   addObserver(b);               
               }
            } 
      }
```

This way, I am maintaining the same list of objects both in super and subclass which only seems a bad workaround to me.

How can I achieve this cleanly with or without using Observer pattern?

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: The typical usage for Observer/Observable is for objects that are only *loosely* coupled; i.e. the Observable's list of Observer's can contain any kind of object and the Observable is pretty much ignorant of what they are. An example might be a UI element (e.g. text field) could be an Observer of a model Observable (e.g. Employee). There really should be *no* code in the Employee that is explicitly aware that one of its Observers is a UI component. JPA mappings are for objects that have a much tighter relationship. The objects involved are explicitly aware of the types of its related objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink what your actual goal is here, at least for me the use case is completely unclear.

- JPA does not create connections between objects unless the connections are stored in the database as columns
- you are not calling the notifyobservers method anywhere so no changes will be actually broadcast
- you should probably be using JPA lifecycle events like @PrePersist and a proper handler instead of observers